# Shell script behaves strangely when called via an Erlang port

Tags: bash, erlang, sh, erlang-ports

When calling shell scripts from Erlang, I generally need their exit status (0 or something else), so I run them using this function:

```
%% in module util
os_cmd_exitstatus(Action, Cmd) ->
    ?debug("~ts starting... Shell command: ~ts", [Action, Cmd]),
    try erlang:open_port({spawn, Cmd}, [exit_status, stderr_to_stdout]) of
        Port -> 
            os_cmd_exitstatus_loop(Action, Port)
    catch
        _:Reason ->
            case Reason of
                badarg ->
                    Message = "Bad input arguments";
                system_limit ->
                    Message = "All available ports in the Erlang emulator are in use";
                _ ->
                    Message = file:format_error(Reason)
            end,
            ?error("~ts: shell command error: ~ts", [Action, Message]),
            error
    end.

os_cmd_exitstatus_loop(Action, Port) ->
    receive
        {Port, {data, Data}} ->
            ?debug("~ts... Shell output: ~ts", [Action, Data]),
            os_cmd_exitstatus_loop(Action, Port);
        {Port, {exit_status, 0}} ->
            ?info("~ts finished successfully", [Action]),
            ok;
        {Port, {exit_status, Status}} ->
            ?error("~ts failed with exit status ~p", [Action, Status]),
            error;
        {'EXIT', Port, Reason} ->
            ?error("~ts failed with port exit: reason ~ts", 
                         [Action, file:format_error(Reason)]),
            error
    end.
```

This worked fine, until I used this to start a script which forks off a program and exits:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME=$1

eog $FILENAME &

exit 0
```

(In the actual usecase, there are quite a few more arguments, and some massaging before they are passed to the program). When run from the terminal, it shows the image and exits immediately, as expected.

But running from Erlang, it doesn't. In the log file I see that it starts fine:

```
22/Mar/2011 13:38:30.518  Debug: Starting player starting... Shell command: /home/aromanov/workspace/gmcontroller/scripts.dummy/image/show-image.sh /home/aromanov/workspace/media/images/9e89471e-eb0b-43f8-8c12-97bbe598e7f7.png
```

and the `eog` window appears. But I *don't* get

```
22/Mar/2011 13:47:14.709  Info: Starting player finished successfully
```

until killing the `eog` process (with `kill` or just closing the window), which isn't suitable for my requirements. Why the difference in behavior? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if you run a command in background with `&` in a shell script and the shell script terminates before the command, then the command gets orphaned.  It might be that erlang trys to prevent orphaned processes in open_port and waits for `eog` to terminate.  Normally if you want to run something in background during a shell script you should put in a `wait` at the end of the script to wait for your background processes to terminate.  But this is exactly what youd don't want to do.

You might try the following in your shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME=$1

daemon eog $FILENAME

# exit 0 not needed: daemon returns 0 if everything is ok
```

If your operating system has a `daemon` command.  I checked in FreeBSD and it has one: [daemon(8)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.2-RELEASE&format=html)

This is not a command available on all Unix alike systems, however there might be a different command doing the same thing in your operating system.

The daemon utility detaches itself from the controlling terminal and executes the program specified by its arguments.

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but I suspect that `eog` somehow stays attached to stdin/stdou as a kind of controling terminal.  Worth a try anyway.

This should also solve the possible problem that job control is **on** erroneously which could also cause the problem.  Since `daemon` does exit normally your shell can't try to wait for the background job on exit because there is none in the shells view.

Having said all this: why not just keep the port open in Erlang while `eog` runs?

Start it with:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME=$1

exec eog $FILENAME
```

Calling it with `exec` doesn't fork it bu replaces the shell process with `eog`.  The exit status you'll see in Erlang will then be the status of `eog` when it terminates.  Also you have the possibility to close the port and terminate `eog` from Erlang if you want to do so.

Comment: Oooh, `daemon(1)` wrapper, excellent idea. I thought about the `exec eog` option, but that wouldn't let Alexey log "Starting playing finished successfully"; his wrapper wouldn't know if the process is waiting ten or twenty seconds before it could be run vs running just fine for ten or twenty seconds. But having the option to kill `eog` from Erlang sounds compellingly worth it.

Comment: But the process in the background wouldn't give this info either.  If there is an error during the preparation phase, this would be detected.  Otherwise either run the shell with option -x (printing commands when they are run) or an echo before starting.  Running the `open_port` with `{line Max_line}` and interpreting the messages you get to find out about progress.

Comment: In fact, keeping the port open (both to be able to kill the program more easily and, more importantly for my usecase, to know when exactly it's finished without polling) was my original design :) Unfortunately, I wasn't able to persuade my manager it would be a good idea.

Comment: `daemon` seems to be the solution, but while `daemon mplayer /home/aromanov/workspace/gmcontroller/working_dir/media/video/635e0b3a-99f0-49e4-8a19-15c1de32a3a2.avi` works fine, `daemon mplayer /home/aromanov/workspace/gmcontroller/working_dir/media/video/635e0b3a-99f0-49e4-8a19-15c1de32a3a2.avi -loop 0` doesn't. Presumably `daemon` thinks `-loop 0` is passed to it, doesn't recognize the option and so doesn't start anything. Quoting the command doesn't help, and manpage doesn't say anything about it. Any ideas?

Comment: You might try using `--` to separate (empty) daemons options from the options of the called command: e.g. `daemon -- mplayer foo.avi -loop 0`.  Normally daemon shouldn't interpret any options after the `command` part but the implementation on your OS seems to be sloppy about it.  Many option parsing functions accept `--` as "here be the end of my options"

Comment: BTW: just tested on FreeBSD: its daemon is not confused by options in the command arguments part.  But it also gladly accepts `--`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your `/bin/sh` doesn't support job control when it isn't run interactively? At least the `/bin/sh` (actually `dash(1)`!) on my Ubuntu system mentions:

```
      -m monitor       Turn on job control (set automatically
                       when interactive).
```

When you run the script from a terminal, the shell probably recognizes that it is being run interactively and supports job control. When you run the shell script as a port, the shell probably runs without job control.

Comment: Making the hashbang line `#!/bin/bash -m` didn't help.

Comment: Alexy, the `-m` was from `dash(1)`, not `bash(1)`, so it would only apply to the `#!/bin/sh` (if your system is like mine, and uses `dash(1)` to supply `/bin/sh`). For `bash(1)` it would be adding `set -m` in the script.

Comment: Help for `bash` on my system also mention `-m`. But yes, this seems to be the problem: `#!/bin/sh -m` gives "22/Mar/2011 15:42:02.507  Debug: Starting player... Shell output: /home/aromanov/workspace/gmcontroller/scripts.dummy/video/video-play.sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off" Using `bash` and `set -m` doesn't give either the error message, but works the same as without `set -m`.

Comment: Alexey, is it fair game to re-write the script in C? It'd be so _easy_ to `fork(2)` and `exec()` the video player, and avoid the job-control mess. Does the shell script provide enough other value that re-writing in C would be difficult?

Comment: Actually, that might be a good idea. Complicates the build a bit, but worth it if there is no better solution.

Comment: I'm not convinced it has anything to do with job control in the shell.

Comment: I correct my last comment: it might have something to do with job control but it is definitly not the preoblem that job control is off.  Job control should always be off for noninteractive shells and it normally also is off.  If by chance job control is somehow erroneously on and something like the `checkjobs` option is on your script wouldn't terminate.